# How to Validate the Field When Empty Post - Ajax, Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I Post the data to Controller using Ajax in Laravel Blade. I Added the Jquery Validation for this Form, When Submit Button Click its goto respective Route and Display Error. How to Validate this Types of Fields.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

 $("#add").click(function(event) {

      if( !$('#ledger_name').val() ) {
          $('#ledger_name').parents('p').addClass('warning');
       }

     event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: $("#add").attr('data-url'),
            data: {
             '_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
            'form_data': $('#Form').serialize(),
            },
            success: function(data) {

                 $('#ledger_name').val('');
                 $('#openning_balance').val('0.00');
                 $('#ob_type').val('');
                 $('#under').val('');
                 $('#ledger_address').val('');
                 $("#newLedger .close").click();
                 $(".result").html(data.success).css({'color': 'green', 'text-align': 'center'}).delay(5000).fadeOut();
            },

         error: function(data)
            {
                var errors = '';
                for(datos in data.responseJSON){
                    errors += data.responseJSON[datos] + '<br>';
                }
                $('#response').show().html(errors); //this is my div with messages
            }

        });

    });

    });
```

**Controller Code :**

```
public function addnewledgers(Request $request){

    $usersid = Auth::user()->id;
    $companyids = Session()->get('companyids'); 

    $values = array();
    parse_str($_POST['form_data'], $values);

    $insertledgers=Ledger::create(['ledger_name'=>$values['ledger_name'],'openning_balance'=>$values['openning_balance'],'ob_type'=>$values['ob_type'],'under'=>$values['under'],'ledger_address'=>$values['ledger_address'],'company_id'=>$companyids,'user_id'=>$usersid,'created_by'=>$usersid]);

    return response()->json(['success' => 'Ledger Details Added Successfully',]);   

    }
```

Comment: You shold tell exactly what types of fields you want to validate. From your code is not obvious what type of fields you have.

Comment: I have Text Fields Only @forexknight

Comment: use laravel validator to validate your fields as the answer given below

Answer (score 2):

You can create validator function like below and get the validation messages to an array.

```
protected function validator(array $data )
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
    ]);
}
```

and call that validation function in your controller method as.

```
$validation = $this->validator($request->all(),true );
if($validation->fails()){
    $errors = $validation->errors();
    return response()->json(
        ['errors' => $errors, 'status' => 'error'],200
    );
}
```

You can change your method as below. (It's recommended to use $request instead of $_POST )

```
public function addnewledgers(Request $request){

    $usersid = Auth::user()->id;
    $companyids = Session()->get('companyids');

    Validator::make( $request->all(), [
            'ledger_name' => 'required',
            //other validations
    ]); 

    if($validation->fails()){
        $errors = $validation->errors();
        return response()->json(
            ['errors' => $errors, 'status' => 'error'],200
        );
    }   


    $values = array();
    parse_str($_POST['form_data'], $values);

    $insertledgers=Ledger::create(['ledger_name'=>$values['ledger_name'],'openning_balance'=>$values['openning_balance'],'ob_type'=>$values['ob_type'],'under'=>$values['under'],'ledger_address'=>$values['ledger_address'],'company_id'=>$companyids,'user_id'=>$usersid,'created_by'=>$usersid]);

    return response()->json(['success' => 'Ledger Details Added Successfully',]);   

}
```

Comment: Json Returned But Error Not Display in Respective Div     error: function(data){ $(".result").html(data.error).css({'color': 'green', 'text-align': 'center'}).delay(5000).fadeOut();  } @Kenath

Comment: user errors instead of error  $(".result").html(data.errors)